# LOB locators from remote tables

Tags: oracle, lob

Having exception from oracle while running following query
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

```
        SELECT 
            OLU.CNIC,
            OLU.LR_USER_NAME NAME,
            OLU.FATHERS_NAME,
            OLU.ADDRESS,
            BATCH_VERIF.CREATED_DATE BATCH_DATE,
            TO_DATE(OLU.ATTRIBUTE9, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')  TRANSLATION_DATE
    FROM ORION.ORN_LR_USER@LIV OLU
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) BATCH_ID, CNIC
        FROM ORION.ORN_LR_BATCH_CNIC@LIV
        WHERE IMPORT_DATE IS NOT NULL AND IMPORTED = 'T'
        GROUP BY CNIC
    ) BATCH_CNIC
            ON (BATCH_CNIC.CNIC = OLU.CNIC
                    AND NVL (OLU.IS_BATCH_VERIFIED, 'F') = 'T' 
                    AND NVL (OLU.ATTRIBUTE10, 'F') = 'T'
                    AND OLU.ATTRIBUTE9 IS NOT NULL) 
        INNER JOIN ORION.ORN_FILE_BATCH_VERIF@LIV BATCH_VERIF
            ON BATCH_VERIF.BATCH_ID = BATCH_CNIC.BATCH_ID;
```

but after commenting TRANSLATION_DATE it is working fine, neither is the column of lob type.. what could be the reason?

```
        SELECT 
            OLU.CNIC,
            OLU.LR_USER_NAME NAME,
            OLU.FATHERS_NAME,
            OLU.ADDRESS,
            BATCH_VERIF.CREATED_DATE BATCH_DATE
            --TO_DATE(OLU.ATTRIBUTE9, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')  TRANSLATION_DATE
    FROM ORION.ORN_LR_USER@LIV OLU
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) BATCH_ID, CNIC
        FROM ORION.ORN_LR_BATCH_CNIC@LIV
        WHERE IMPORT_DATE IS NOT NULL AND IMPORTED = 'T'
        GROUP BY CNIC
    ) BATCH_CNIC
            ON (BATCH_CNIC.CNIC = OLU.CNIC
                    AND NVL (OLU.IS_BATCH_VERIFIED, 'F') = 'T' 
                    AND NVL (OLU.ATTRIBUTE10, 'F') = 'T'
                    AND OLU.ATTRIBUTE9 IS NOT NULL) 
        INNER JOIN ORION.ORN_FILE_BATCH_VERIF@LIV BATCH_VERIF
            ON BATCH_VERIF.BATCH_ID = BATCH_CNIC.BATCH_ID;
```

Comment: ATTRIBUTE9 is the varchar2 column

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying ATTRIBUTE9 is not a CLOB column. Are you sure? If so, are any columns in the referenced tables of type CLOB?

Comment: yea, ATTRIBUTE9 is not a CLOB column. There are CLOB columns in referenced table but they are not being selected in any query. If you compare both scripts you will notice the difference i want to share.

Comment: What size is `ATTRIBUTE9`, and what are the database character sets? I think it's possible that a large string (e.g. `varchar2(4000)` can cause this if the character sets are different, and multiple bytes are allocated over the link for each character; it effectively becomes an implicit CLOB. Long time since i saw that though, I'll try to dig something up.

Comment: size of ATTRIBUTE9 512 Byte, size of this column is no matter because i have selected this column before and found no issue.. problem arise when i converted this column into date type.

Comment: Which version and patch level of Oracle are you using? (The first line from `select banner from v$version`)

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi

Answer (score 0):

> "problem arise when i converted this column into date type"

Hmmm, sounds like it may be an Oracle bug. But maybe you can work around it with this trick:

```
TO_DATE(substr(OLU.ATTRIBUTE9, 1, 22), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') TRANSLATION_DATE
```

Comment: bug at which end? oracle?